# How to put Permissions and Codebase attributes into third-party jar's manifest?

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp

As stated in [*Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 25 (JDK 7u25)*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html),
a warning is printed in the console if the manifest file of an application deployed using Java Web Start doesn't have the Permissions an Codebase attributes described in [*Preventing RIAs from Being Repurposed*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/no_redeploy.html).

For my JARs, it is trivial to add the properties; it is even trivial for third-party jars not digitally signed: modify the manifest and sign (same as my JARs).
What if I have third-party digitally signed jars? It seems that a hash of the entire manifest file is used in the verification process, so it may not be possible to modify the manifest without invalidating the signature applied using [*jarsigner—JAR Signing and Verification Tool*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html).

Is this right? Is there any solution?

Comment: As `jarsigner` allows *Multiple Signatures for a JAR File*, what happens what you try it?

Comment: I can modifiy the manifest and resign the jar invalidating the third party signature.
The problem here is the jar in question is BoucyCastle provider and if the BC signature is not verified the JRE doesn't trust the provider.

Comment: How does your signing `BoucyCastle` invalidate the original signature?

Comment: I modify the manifest: I have to add Permissions and Codebase attributes.

Comment: Have you asked the `BouncyCastle` maintainers to add the attributes or tried building your own signed JAR?

Comment: No yet, but it seems the only possible solution.They have to add Permissions: all-permissions Codebase: * into the manifest to support all possible usages.
I think that these new attributes will bring new problems without security benefits

Comment: Is building your own signed `BouncyCastle` JAR practical?

Comment: One of the BC maintainers said they added the attributes in the manifest of the new beta version, but Oracle can't assume is ever possible to replace a third party signature or have a fix from the producer... In the case of BC, as I know, a generic valid signature is not enough, it is needed a certificate Oracle trusts.

Answer (score 0):

i made a little ant script for this purpose. the idea is simple:

- for each jar

  - extract content in a temp directory
  - re-jar excluding *.RSA and *.SF files (adding permissions too)
  - sign with my own certificate

  ```
  <property name="keystore" value="../keystores/store/keystore.jks" />
  <property name="storetype" value="jks" />
  <property name="storepass" value="password" />
  <property name="keypass" value="${storepass}" />

  <target name="unsign-all">
      <foreach target="_re-jar" param="currentFile" parallel="false">
          <path>
              <fileset dir="WebContent/dir_contains_jars" casesensitive="yes">
                  <include name="**/*.jar" />
              </fileset>
          </path>
      </foreach>

      <move todir="WebContent/dir_contains_jars" overwrite="true">
          <fileset dir="WebContent/dir_contains_jars.tmp" casesensitive="yes">
              <include name="**/*.jar" />
          </fileset>
      </move>

      <delete dir="WebContent/dir_contains_jars.tmp" />
  </target>

  <target name="sign-all">
      <apply executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\jarsigner">
          <arg line="-keystore ${keystore} -storetype ${storetype} -storepass ${storepass} -keypass ${keypass}" />
          <srcfile />
          <arg line="alias_name" />

          <fileset dir="WebContent/dir_contains_jars" casesensitive="yes">
              <include name="**/*.jar" />
          </fileset>
      </apply>
  </target>

  <target name="_re-jar">
      <basename property="filename" file="${currentFile}" />

      <jar destfile="WebContent/dir_contains_jars.tmp/${filename}">
          <zipfileset src="${currentFile}">
              <exclude name="META-INF/**.RSA" />
              <exclude name="META-INF/**.SF" />
          </zipfileset>
          <manifest>
              <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions" />
              <attribute name="Codebase" value="*" />
              <attribute name="Application-Name" value="jnlpApplicationName" />
          </manifest>
      </jar>
  </target>
  ```